# Finding the matrix $A$ of $T$ with respect to the basis

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be given by 
>   $$T\left(\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix} x-y \\ y-z \\ z-x \end{bmatrix}$$
>   Find the matrix $A$ of $T$ with respect to the basis
>   $$\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

**My try:**

I found $T\left(\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}\right)=x\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}+y\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Now,

$$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

In the same way I found the other matrices as 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
Now, 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}+c\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
So, if I find $a,b,c$ then that will become the first row of my required matrix right? Can anyone tell whether this method is correct or not?

Comment: Recall that the i-th column of the matrix should be the i-th basis vector passed through the transformation and than shown in the given basis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't actually applied $T$ to any of the basis vectors (the matrix you have there is the matrix with the basis vectors as columns, and as such it has little to do with $T$).

If you apply $T$ to the first basis vector, you get $[-1,-1,2]^T$. Now *that* is the vector you should express as a linear combination of the basis vectors, and the coefficients make up the first *column* of $A$.